# DB::Exception: Received from localhost:8000. DB::Exception: Number of columns doesn't match

Tags: clickhouse

create table:-

```sql
CREATE TABLE default.bankIfsc (
`event_date` Date DEFAULT toDate(now()), 
`id` Int32, 
`uid` Int32, 
`nid` Int32, 
`bank` String, 
`ifsc_code` String, 
`micr_code` String, 
`branch` String, 
`address` String, 
`contact` String, 
`city` String, 
`district` String, 
`state` String, 
`content` String, 
`feature_image` String, 
`var1` String, 
`var2` String, 
`var3` String, 
`var4` String, 
`var5` String, 
`createdtime` Int32, 
`createdtimestr` DateTime DEFAULT toDateTime(createdtime), 
`updatedtime` Int32, 
`updatedtimestr` DateTime DEFAULT toDateTime(updatedtime), 
`status` Int32) ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(event_date, id, 8192)
```

datastore in this table and table view:-

```sql
CREATE TABLE default.bankIfsc_bck (
`id` Int32, 
`uid` Int32, 
`nid` Int32, 
`bank` String, 
`ifsc_code` String, 
`micr_code` String, 
`branch` String, 
`address` String, 
`contact` String, 
`city` String, 
`district` String, 
`state` String, 
`content` String, 
`feature_image` String, 
`var1` String, 
`var2` String, 
`var3` String, 
`var4` String, 
`var5` String, 
`createdtime` Int32, 
`createdtimestr` DateTime, 
`updatedtime` Int32, 
`updatedtimestr` DateTime, 
`status` Int32) ENGINE = Log
```

insert data:-

```sql
INSERT INTO bankIfsc ( id, uid, nid, bank, ifsc_code, micr_code, branch,
 address, contact, city, district, state, content, feature_image, var1,
 var2, var3, var4, var5, createdtime, createdtimestr, updatedtime, 
updatedtimestr, status ) 
SELECT (id, uid, nid, bank, ifsc_code, micr_code, branch, address, 
contact, city, district, state, content, feature_image, var1, var2, var3, 
var4, var5, createdtime, createdtimestr, updatedtime, updatedtimestr,
 status) 
FROM bankIfsc_bck;
```

The number of columns doesn't match.
I got this error anyone help, please

Answer (score 1):

```
( ) -- makes tuple datatype.

2 columns -- select 1,2
desc (select 1,2)
┌─name─┬─type──┬
│ 1    │ UInt8 │
│ 2    │ UInt8 │
└──────┴───────┴

1 column -- select (1,2)    
desc (select (1,2))
─name────────┬─type────────────────┬
 tuple(1, 2) │ Tuple(UInt8, UInt8) │
─────────────┴─────────────────────┴
```

remove ( ) from your select

```
SELECT id, uid, nid, bank, ifsc_code, micr_code, branch, address, 
contact, city, district, state, content, feature_image, var1, var2, var3, 
var4, var5, createdtime, createdtimestr, updatedtime, updatedtimestr,
 status
FROM bankIfsc_bck;
```